# Change default background colour of Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This could have been asked and found a lot of posts for bootsrap navbar but still my issue is not fixed.
The code of html with bootsrap is below and I am trying to change background color of navbar from grey as default to orange or something else but it's not working, unless i use !important and I do not want to use !important.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: update; code is not working with space to add here no idea how to put code here

Comment: Hey , check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow for help how to add your code. If you look at the text body of your post when editing, 7 icons in you'll see a piece of paper with brackets, you can post your code there as well. (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change `bg-light` to a custom name like say, `bg-orange` or whatever name you want to use like this:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-orange">
    ....
</nav>
```

And then reference the new class-name that you specified (here, we used `bg-orange`) to your css like this:

**CSS:**

```
.bg-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

---

Here's a **jsFiddle** with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/hk0yp8a1/1/

---

**P.S.** If your custom background color is a dark color, you can also change the `navbar-light` class to `navbar-dark` so that the font-color will change to adapt to a dark-colored color scheme as can be seen in this jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/hk0yp8a1/6/

Comment: You're the real MVP man it worked. Asked in Reddit didn't got the correct answer as some said to use !important bla bla bla, but this one worked by changing to bg-orange and now in CSS I can change without !Important by this ".bg-orange{
    background-color: red;
}"
Thank you man :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
Did upvote but I am still not in good Reputation man :(

Comment: will definitely do questions but once 5 days have passed that sucks hahaha, thank anyway man